# Mysql columns to represent 6:00 am one day and 8:00 next day on specific days

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `FlightOperatedby` (
  `2-let ID` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `flight #` int DEFAULT 0,
  `departing airport` char(3),
  `arriving airport` char(3),
  `departing time` timestamp,
  `arriving time` timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (`2-let ID`,`flight #`)
) 

LOCK TABLES `FlightOperatedby` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `FlightOperatedby` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `FlightOperatedby` VALUES ('AA', 1, 'JFK', 'DEL', '6:00:00am every Monday, Wednesday, and Saturday', '8:00am on every Tuesday, Thursday, and Sunday');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `FlightOperatedby` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I want to create a table called FlightOperatedBy that contains flights like from JFK to DEL and I want to represent that one flight could be departing at 6:00 am on one day, and it would arrive at 8:00am on the next day. How would I insert this into the table?

Comment: do you want each record to represent a single flight (leaving 6am on a specific day), or that in general there is a flight leaving at 6am and arriving at 8am the following day?  from your primary key, I'm guessing the latter

Comment: how you should store it highly depends on how you plan to use this data.  give us some idea what kinds of queries (and what their results will look like) you plan to do

Comment: I want to query the data based on the date from when a user will access the system. So the customer can see flights that will leave to their destination plus or minus 3 days from when they want to leave. So if they are accessing the system tomorrow 11/16, and they want to leaving to Delhi on 11/20, they can see flights from 11/17 to 11/20 that are leaving to Delhi. I want to create a flight to Delhi that will leave JFK on Mondays, Wednesdays, and Saturdays at 6:00am, and it would arrive to DEL on Tuesdays, Thursdays, and Sundays at 8:00am.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably not store a destination time, just a start time, timezone for that start time, and duration.  Because there are multiple days of the week per flight, I would store those in a separate table with one row per flight/day of week.

I encourage you to not make column names that require quoting - so no spaces or special characters or beginning with a digit.  Stick to just letters and underscores.

Comment: For my assignment, I have to put a start and end time to the flight. The start time and duration would not be enough.

Comment: does the end time stay the same even with DST changes?  that sounds incorrect

Comment: but if so, I would store an end time and a days_later column that would be 0 most of the time and 1 if the end time is the following day